# Uninitialized constant RSpec when adding gem

Tags: ruby, rspec, rubygems, capybara

I am creating some automated tests using Cucumber and Capybara. I want to add the Touch Action gem (https://github.com/Ricardonacif/touch_action). I added the gem and then in my env file required it but i am getting the following error. I am really confused as to whether i should be creating a separate helper file but i tried something along these lines and still got the same error. Could anyone offer any advice as to how to resolve this?

```
    uninitialized constant RSpec (NameError)
/Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/touch_action-1.3.0/lib/touch_action/capybara_rspec_helper.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/touch_action-1.3.0/lib/touch_action.rb:12:in `require'
/Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/touch_action-1.3.0/lib/touch_action.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/em/reallyenglish/learning_specs/learning-platform-specs/features/support/env.rb:3:in `require'
/Users/em/reallyenglish/learning_specs/learning-platform-specs/features/support/env.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cucumber-2.0.0/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:94:in `load'
/Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cucumber-2.0.0/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:94:in `load_code_file'
/Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cucumber-2.0.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:237:in `load_file'
/Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cucumber-2.0.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:97:in `block in load_files!'
/Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cucumber-2.0.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:96:in `each'
/Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cucumber-2.0.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:96:in `load_files!'
/Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cucumber-2.0.0/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:242:in `load_step_definitions'
/Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cucumber-2.0.0/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:65:in `run!'
/Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cucumber-2.0.0/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:38:in `execute!'
/Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cucumber-2.0.0/bin/cucumber:9:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
/Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/cucumber:23:in `<main>'
/Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

**Gemfile**

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem 'rake'
gem 'touch_action'

group(:test) do
  gem 'cucumber'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end
```

**env.rb**

```
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/cucumber'
require 'touch_action'

Capybara.configure do |config|
    config.default_selector = :css
  config.default_driver = :selenium
  config.app_host   = 'http://testem.co.uk
    # Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = false --video testing
    config.include Capybara::DSL
end

After do
  page.execute_script("window.localStorage.clear()")
end
```

Comment: why the rails generate command when it is not a rails app as such?

Comment: are you asking yourself that?  what do you mean about the rails generate?  and what is the comand that is causing this error?

Comment: no it looks like someone removed their comment! They suggested running rails generate rspec install

Comment: ha, okay. glad you are not talking to yourself :p  what is the command that causes that error?

Comment: Thanks! it is when i run cucumber that i get the error. This is only with the touch action gem set up as shown in my question.

Comment: and before you added the touch action gem it was working as expected? and you are using `env.rb` as a spec helper or what/

Comment: it was working fine until i put require 'touch-action' in the env.rb which is all i have-i have not needed to use a spec helper but maybe this is where i am having problems

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79009/discussion-between-dax-and-em8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After our chat discussion, it seems that `touch-action` needs `rspec` to be explicitly required.  Your `env.rb` file should look like this:

```
require 'rspec'
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/cucumber'
require 'touch_action'
```